# Code Question in regards to 120V / 20 amps

Tags: electrical

I am looking to install a [24-outlet Vertical Power Strip](http://www.tripplite.com/en/products/model.cfm?txtModelID=197) (Tripp Lite PS7224-20), to help have enough plugs for my computer equipment in the basement. Currently I have traced out the wire in the house from the breaker to a covered junction box. The Circuit breaker is 20 amps, and the wiring is 12/2 with a ground to the Junction box. At the Junction Box I have the Pool light on the line.

My question is awhile ago I added a 12/2 with ground out of that junction box for the computer equipment. Is this allowed as long as I used the Romex wire with the plastic junction boxes to house the outlet plug(120V). I want to keep that line and add an additional line that will be connected to a NEMA L5-20R which is needed for the PS277-20(20 amp). I will be moving the load of the devices over to the 20 amp line, and where the current equipment is will be only used to control 1 small device. Currently there is no tripping of the circut so the load is ok on the line. I am really only worried about if its to Code. Any help would be appricated. Sorry for the long winded post, just trying to give a good picture since I can't upload a photo

Comment: I would check carefully regarding circuits for pool lights. I am not an expert on the Electrical Code but it seems likely that the pool light should be a dedicated circuit with its own GFI / AFCI breaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, this is allowed, provided you have enough room in the boxes for the number of conductors coming through and connecting within.  If not, you may need a larger junction box.  For a continuous 20A load, you would need a separate line, but in this case, you are simply attaching a device with a 20A plug that itself provides multiple outlets (not a continuous load).

Since your pool lamp could potentially short or cause other issues (it being near water, etc.), you should consider moving it to another circuit so that you don't risk tripping the breaker on your computer equipment.